# rake db:migrate is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working through the rails tutorial and have gotten stuck. Starting at Listing 8.16 I have made the following modifications to `<timestamp>_add_remember_token_to_users.rb`:

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
    add_index  :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

The guide then says to update dev & test db as usual:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

My User test for the *remember_token* is still failing so I took a look at the *user* table in dev and tests database with command line sqlite3. They look like this:

```
sqlite> .schema users
CREATE TABLE "users" (
   "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
   "name" varchar(255), 
   "email" varchar(255), 
   "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, 
   "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, 
   "password_digest" varchar(255));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_email" ON "users" ("email");
```

It seems like my migration has not been run yet but I do not know how to force it to run.

Comment: What is the output of the rake tasks?

Comment: If you mean what output is there after running bundle exec rake db:migrate - there is no output, just a new prompt.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try to rebuild your database structure(**WARNING:** all db-data will be lost):

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

If you use Rails < 4.1, don't forget to prepare test database:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

This is the easiest solution since you are working with tutorial. However in production or having important data in development you should take time to investigate the issue. In this case you most likely had created an empty migration, ran `rake db:migrate`, then added instructions to the migration, so you don't see a new field and further `rake db:migrate` does nothing. To resolve this issue you need to comment your `change` instructions, perform `rake db:rollback`, uncomment instructions and then `rake db:migrate` to apply instructions you missed.

Comment: This did fix my database issue. Thanks. Heads up though, all of my tests started failing until I remembered to re-run $ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare

Comment: This worked. Just had to update to do bundle exec rails db{...} for Rails 5.1. In fact, bundle exec portion may even be optional.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue as the initial question. `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate` wasn't adding remember_token to the .db and Latha Doddikadi's answer worked for me.

I did:

```
rake db:rollback
```

and then:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

which added the remember_token field to the database followed by:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

which passed.

```
Finished in 0.92841 seconds
21 examples, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 5):

Roll back and then re run the migration it might work.

```
     rake db:rollback
```

And after rolling back re run your migrations again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bizarre case of the last migration simply refusing to run. I'd created the migration file manually. So I deleted it and remade the migration using

```rb
rails g migration ...
```

and copied the code into the new file and it ran.

I didn't discover why manually creating that file didn't work; all I know is doing it the 'right/rails way' fixed the issue.

Leaving this here in case it helps someone else.