# rake db:migrate does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm following this [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), 
and I'm having a problem when running `rake db:migrate`

In `db/migrate` I have the `create_post.rb` file:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But it does not create the table.
My `database.yml` file is:

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 database: blog_development
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password:
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

The output from rake `db:migrate` seems ok.

I'm using `phpMyAdmin` to handle the database, which is correctly created manually by me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you check if your table is created in phpMyAdmin or with the rails console ?

Comment: have you created this migration file from terminal or manually if manually make sure time stamp is larger than last migration time stamp..

Comment: no errors from output:

Comment: C:\Sites\blog>rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20140325180152
== 20140325180152 CreatePosts: reverting ======================================
-- drop_table(:posts)
   -> 0.0010s
== 20140325180152 CreatePosts: reverted (0.0250s) =============================

== 20140325180152 CreatePosts: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:posts)
   -> 0.0390s
== 20140325180152 CreatePosts: migrated (0.0400s) =============================

Comment: if no out put this means rake is not finding any migration to run..check your schema file if posts is there ?

Comment: are you looking at the correct database (`blog_development`)?

Comment: yes, I look into the correct database. 

mysql> select * from posts;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'blog_development.posts' doesn't exist

Comment: could be a problem with the adapter: mysql2 ??

Comment: drop the database and run the migration again. Once a migration is executed, its timestamp is added to the schema so that when the next time you run db:migrate, the migrations that have already been executed dont execute again.

Comment: Also, are you sure phpmyadmin is looking at the correct place?  Try this from the command line: mysql -uroot blog_development -e "show tables;"

Comment: I experienced the same problem - I deleted the migration file, ran rake db:migrate - added migration again file and then ran again rake db:migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are connecting to the right database everything seems fine to me.. I had a similar problem a few weeks ago and the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896488/rake-dbmigrate-is-not-working) question fixed my issue.

Here are the steps to run:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

I hope it will fix your problem.

**WARNING: this will erase your database.**

Comment: no errors in output from these commands. But the table is still not created :/

Comment: could be a problem with the adapter: mysql2 ??

Comment: How do you check if your table is created? Through phpMyAdmin or through the Rails console? If you check the console with the command: 'Post', it doesn't show you any tables or table shema. First try to use 'Post.count' and after that 'Post'. This connects the console to the database and gives you information about it.

Comment: ok! For some reason the table exist in Rails console (sqlite):

sqlite> select * from posts;
sqlite>     

but not in mysql

Answer (score 1):

Could you please tell which OS you got?
Delete the line:

```
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and run:

```
db:migrate
```

Give the output of:

```
db:migrate:status
```

If this is not working for you, you could also try to add:

```
host: 127.0.0.1
```

to your **database.yml** file

Comment: ok thanks. Table IS created in sqlite3 (previous config I used).
The problem then is...why it is not created in mysql?

Comment: Maybe you need to remove gem 'sqlite3' in your Gemfile then run bundle install again, so that rails will only detect mysql2 in your Gemfile :)

Answer (score 1):

If nothing stated above works please do check your schema.rb for migration contents. If migration contents are already there then just do the below command in production:

rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production.