# Rake db:migrate is not working even not giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rake, dbmigrate

I have rail's project and it was working perfectly fine but, at some point I have done something that I haven't remember and `rake db:migrate` stopped working.
I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686452/rake-dbmigrate-does-nothing) but didn't work.
The response for `rake db:migrate` is

```
C:\Users\Mayur\Documents\Project>bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

I am using postgresql database, ruby-2.0.0 and rails 4.2

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: project
  username: admin
  password: admin
  pool: 5
```

Comment: Can you put your `database.yml` here?

Comment: I have added the database.yml file. It's contain only development mode

Comment: Did you first create the database - Postgresql needs it unlike Sqlite3?  `rake db:create`

Comment: yes, i have created database using pgadmin.